# Rails 3 routes double check on match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

currently, I have this on my routes.rb

```
match '/:username' => 'profiles#show', :as => :public_profile
```

now I want to use this format, and add another parameter to make another match for another route.
I don't know how to explain this but let me give you an example.
Suppose with that match above:

```
http://example.com/foo_username
```

this connects to the profile of foo_username.
Now I want to have a url like this:

```
http://example.com/foo_username/5-my-story
```

This link should go to the stories#show action with 5-my-story as its id (slug), and this story is owned by the username provided in the path. How do I configure that in routes?
I tried this one:

```
match '/:username/:id' => 'stories#show', :as => public_story
```

It works, but when I change the parameter of the username, it still goes to the story. It should return a route not found because the username does not own the story.

How do I best implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you'll have something like this:

```
@story = Story.find(params[:id])
```

You need to restrict this to the user's stories maybe like this

```
@user = User.find_by_username( params[:username] )
@story = @user.stories.find(params[:id])
```

You then have to check if @story is nil, and return a 404 if not.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this to suit your needs:

```
# stories_controller.rb

def show
  @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @story.user.name == params[:username]
  # ...
end
```